# Cannot use math.pow function in NodeMCU/ESP8266

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I need the math.pow function in NodeMCU/ESP8266 but I cannot include the math library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try using the [exponentiation `^` operator](http://www.lua.org/pil/3.1.html) instead of `math.pow`: `2^3 == 8`.